# Метод вызывает утечку памяти, подскажите где проблема

Tags: c#

Добрый день.
Метод вызывает утечку памяти, подскажите опытным взглядом где кроется проблема:

```
public bool DownloadImage(string URL, string Path, string FileName, string Referer)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
            wr.Timeout = 30000;
            wr.Referer = Referer;
            wr.KeepAlive = true;
            wr.UserAgent = UserAgent;
            wr.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
            Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream();

            byte[] inBuf = new byte[100000];
            int bytesReadTotal = 0;

            FileStream fstr = new FileStream(Path + FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            while (true)
            {
                int n = str.Read(inBuf, 0, 100000);
                if ((n == 0) || (n == -1))
                {
                    break;
                }

                fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, n);
                bytesReadTotal += n;
            }

            str.Close();
            fstr.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На идиоматическом C# ваш код записывается так:

```
public void DownloadImage(Uri uri, string fullPath, string referer)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Referer", referer);
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", UserAgent);
        client.DownloadFile(uri, fullPath);        
    }
}
```

Вы не должны возвращать true/false, просто пробрасывайте исключение.

---

Проблема с таймаутом легко обходится (код [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052637/276994)):

```
public class ConfigurableWebClient : WebClient
{
    public int Timeout { get; private set; }
    public ConfigurableWebClient() : this(30000) { }
    public ConfigurableWebClient(int timeout) { this.Timeout = timeout; }
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request != null)
            request.Timeout = this.Timeout;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Можно доделать `ConfigurableWebClient`, чтобы он настраивал `WebRequest` как вам угодно. А черновую работу типа загрузки файла через буфер доверьте лучше готовому коду.

Использовать точно так же:

```
using (var client = new ConfigurableWebClient(timeout: 30000))
{
    client.Headers.Add("Referer", referer);
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", UserAgent);
    client.DownloadFile(uri, fullPath);        
}
```

Comment: WebClient - это огрызок (таймаута нет). Не хочу я возвращать и обрабатывать эксепшн, проще работать с bool.

Comment: @z668:

1. `timeout` — [не большая проблема](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3052637/276994).
2. А вот возврат флага ошибки — бяка, чревато либо его игнорированием, либо заполнением кода проверками на ошибку после каждой строки. Не делайте так.

Comment: @z668: Обновил ответ.

Comment: @VladD благодарю, интернет просто вылетал.

Comment: @z668: Не стоит благодарности. Пишите, если не будет работать, разберёмся.

Answer (score 2):

Если возникнет исключение, то управление будет передано в блок catch и потоки fstr и str не будут закрыты.

попробуйте использовать для них try-with-resource, для автоматического закрытия открытых потоков.

Comment: try-with-resource - подскажите как это будет выглядеть для C#? Нашел только примеры для Java.

Comment: для C# данная конструкция отсутствует, добавьте в блок catch закрытие потоков str и fstr, если они открыты.

Comment: Кто заплюсовал «отсутствует»? Ещё как присутствует, и появилась там пораньше, чем в Java. Курите `IDisposable` и `using`.

Comment: @VladD, я, поверил на слово =) Ну ничего страшного, главное проблема найдена. Просто не сразу понял о чем речь.